# Grails Non SSL Email Configuratoin

Tags: email, ssl, grails, haraka

I want to sent email from grails application. Mail server is HARAKA which does not support ssl. Instead of SSL it uses TLS.
Configuration is:

```
mail `{`
`host = "mm13.us1.emailsrv.net"`
`port = 2525`
`username = "user"`
`password = "pass****"`
`props` = `[` 
         `"mail.smtp.auth":"true",`
         `"mail.smtp.port":"2525",`
         `"mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false",`
         `"mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true"`
      `]`
`}`
```

Facing Error:

> Problem sending email Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

Comment: try to add in props "mail.smtp.ssl.trust":"mm13.us1.emailsrv.net" (I think in your complete log there is "Unable To Find Valid Certificate" message or something like this). Give us more about the logs